# Find out the error in a windows debugger report

Tags: windows, crash, debugging, report

I need help finding on what is wrong on the following file which have been produced in windows debbuger program. This is the report:

```
Microsoft (R) Windows Debugger Version 6.11.0001.404 X86
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

CommandLine: "C:\Program Files\ChangValues\chnValues.exe"
Symbol search path is: symsrv*symsrv.dll*c:\logspas*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
Executable search path is: 
ModLoad: 00400000 004cc000   chnValues.exe
ModLoad: 77f70000 77ff5000   ntdll.dll
ModLoad: 79000000 79046000   C:\WINNT\system32\mscoree.dll
ModLoad: 77e60000 77f25000   C:\WINNT\system32\KERNEL32.dll

eax=00000000 ebx=00131f04 ecx=00000009 edx=00000000 esi=7ffdf000 edi=00131f78
eip=77f713b1 esp=0012f984 ebp=0012fc98 iopl=0         nv up ei pl nz na po nc
cs=001b  ss=0023  ds=0023  es=0023  fs=003b  gs=0000             efl=00000202
ntdll!DbgBreakPoint:
77f713b1 cc              int     3
0:000> g
ModLoad: 79090000 790f2000   C:\WINNT\system32\ADVAPI32.dll
ModLoad: 77d20000 77d91000   C:\WINNT\system32\RPCRT4.DLL
ModLoad: 70a70000 70ad6000   C:\WINNT\system32\SHLWAPI.dll
ModLoad: 78000000 78045000   C:\WINNT\system32\msvcrt.dll
ModLoad: 77f30000 77f6b000   C:\WINNT\system32\GDI32.dll
ModLoad: 783f0000 7844f000   C:\WINNT\system32\USER32.dll
ModLoad: 79e70000 7a3ff000   c:\WINNT\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\mscorwks.dll
ModLoad: 78130000 781cb000   C:\WINNT\system32\MSVCR80.dll
ModLoad: 77550000 7779e000   C:\WINNT\system32\shell32.dll
ModLoad: 71710000 71794000   C:\WINNT\system32\COMCTL32.dll
ModLoad: 02c50000 03786000   C:\WINNT\assembly\NativeImages_v2.0.50727_32\mscorlib\642534209e13d16e93b80a628742d2ee\mscorlib.ni.dll
ModLoad: 77a40000 77b2f000   C:\WINNT\system32\ole32.dll
ModLoad: 6e310000 6e316000   C:\WINNT\system32\INDICDLL.dll
ModLoad: 75de0000 75dfa000   C:\WINNT\system32\IMM32.dll
ModLoad: 7a440000 7ac2a000   C:\WINNT\assembly\NativeImages_v2.0.50727_32\System\36dbfcf62e07d819b3de533898868ecf\System.ni.dll
ModLoad: 5e430000 5e5de000   C:\WINNT\assembly\NativeImages_v2.0.50727_32\Microsoft.VisualBas#\900525e192ca3d523143207ac11ae5f5\Microsoft.VisualBasic.ni.dll
ModLoad: 037b0000 03806000   c:\WINNT\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\mscorjit.dll
ModLoad: 7ade0000 7af7c000   C:\WINNT\assembly\NativeImages_v2.0.50727_32\System.Drawing\c91f68c2920882e02aec00eeabb6b415\System.Drawing.ni.dll
ModLoad: 7afd0000 7bc6c000   C:\WINNT\assembly\NativeImages_v2.0.50727_32\System.Windows.Forms\0c70e5d82578be2f6c0dde89182261c5\System.Windows.Forms.ni.dll
ModLoad: 67770000 677bc000   System.Runtime.Remoting.dll
ModLoad: 67770000 677bc000   C:\WINNT\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Runtime.Remoting\2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Runtime.Remoting.dll
ModLoad: 60340000 60348000   c:\WINNT\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\culture.dll
(35c.a28): C++ EH exception - code e06d7363 (first chance)
(35c.a28): CLR exception - code e0434f4d (first chance)
ModLoad: 11000000 11166000   image11000000
ModLoad: 7ca00000 7ca23000   C:\WINNT\system32\rsaenh.dll
ModLoad: 78ee0000 78f42000   C:\WINNT\system32\USERENV.dll
ModLoad: 79580000 79607000   C:\WINNT\system32\CRYPT32.dll
ModLoad: 773d0000 773e0000   C:\WINNT\system32\MSASN1.DLL
ModLoad: 64020000 64033000   c:\WINNT\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\mscorsec.dll
ModLoad: 768c0000 768eb000   C:\WINNT\system32\WINTRUST.dll
ModLoad: 77910000 77933000   C:\WINNT\system32\IMAGEHLP.dll
ModLoad: 77250000 772bc000   C:\WINNT\system32\RichEd20.dll
ModLoad: 79170000 7917f000   C:\WINNT\system32\secur32.dll
ModLoad: 750d0000 7511f000   C:\WINNT\system32\netapi32.dll
ModLoad: 77be0000 77bf1000   C:\WINNT\system32\NTDSAPI.dll
ModLoad: 77970000 77994000   C:\WINNT\system32\DNSAPI.DLL
ModLoad: 74fa0000 74fa9000   C:\WINNT\system32\WSOCK32.DLL
ModLoad: 74f80000 74f94000   C:\WINNT\system32\WS2_32.DLL
ModLoad: 74f70000 74f78000   C:\WINNT\system32\WS2HELP.DLL
ModLoad: 77940000 7796b000   C:\WINNT\system32\WLDAP32.DLL
ModLoad: 75120000 75126000   C:\WINNT\system32\NETRAP.dll
ModLoad: 750b0000 750bf000   C:\WINNT\system32\SAMLIB.dll
ModLoad: 79540000 79552000   C:\WINNT\system32\cryptnet.dll
ModLoad: 76080000 760d0000   C:\WINNT\system32\WINHTTP.DLL
ModLoad: 75a30000 75a35000   C:\WINNT\system32\SENSAPI.DLL
ModLoad: 11000000 11166000   C:\Program Files\Αλλαγή Τιμών\C1.Win.C1TrueDBGrid.2.dll
ModLoad: 777e0000 777e7000   C:\WINNT\system32\VERSION.dll
ModLoad: 75930000 75936000   C:\WINNT\system32\LZ32.DLL
ModLoad: 04530000 045d2000   C:\WINNT\assembly\GAC\Oracle.DataAccess\1.102.2.20__89b483f429c47342\Oracle.DataAccess.dll
ModLoad: 65160000 6581e000   C:\WINNT\assembly\NativeImages_v2.0.50727_32\System.Data\51388700863219403ce1eaead4bb1e0d\System.Data.ni.dll
ModLoad: 64e70000 6515c000   System.Data.dll
ModLoad: 64e70000 6515c000   C:\WINNT\assembly\GAC_32\System.Data\2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.dll
ModLoad: 04980000 049b6000   C:\Program Files\ChangValues\C1.Win.C1Sizer.2.dll
ModLoad: 70d00000 70e91000   c:\WINNT\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Gdiplus.dll
(35c.a28): C++ EH exception - code e06d7363 (first chance)
(35c.a28): CLR exception - code e0434f4d (first chance)
(35c.a28): CLR exception - code e0434f4d (first chance)
(35c.a28): CLR exception - code e0434f4d (first chance)
(35c.a28): CLR exception - code e0434f4d (first chance)
(35c.a28): CLR exception - code e0434f4d (first chance)
(35c.a28): CLR exception - code e0434f4d (first chance)
(35c.a28): CLR exception - code e0434f4d (!!! second chance !!!)
eax=0012f200 ebx=e0434f4d ecx=00000000 edx=00000029 esi=0012f28c edi=0012f218
eip=77e8bbf3 esp=0012f1f8 ebp=0012f250 iopl=0         nv up ei pl nz na po nc
cs=001b  ss=0023  ds=0023  es=0023  fs=003b  gs=0000             efl=00000202
KERNEL32!RaiseException+0x56:
77e8bbf3 5f              pop     edi
0:000> g
WARNING: Continuing a non-continuable exception
(35c.a28): Break instruction exception - code 80000003 (first chance)
eax=00000001 ebx=00000000 ecx=00000000 edx=0012f22c esi=00000000 edi=79f071bc
eip=77f713b1 esp=0012ed8c ebp=0012f238 iopl=0         nv up ei pl nz na po nc
cs=001b  ss=0023  ds=0023  es=0023  fs=003b  gs=0000             efl=00000202
ntdll!DbgBreakPoint:
77f713b1 cc              int     3
0:000> g
eax=00000000 ebx=00000000 ecx=0012ef48 edx=00000000 esi=77f7ee04 edi=80131506
eip=77f7ee0f esp=0012ef54 ebp=0012f01c iopl=0         nv up ei pl zr na pe nc
cs=001b  ss=0023  ds=0023  es=0023  fs=003b  gs=0000             efl=00000246
ntdll!NtTerminateProcess+0xb:
77f7ee0f c20800          ret     8
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you're using COM/CLR interop, and are trying to throw a C++ exception over COM boundaries.

This isn't allowed. Catch the exception at COM level and return an error HRESULT.

Comment: First of all thanks for your reply. But i am not familliar with this debug application which runs on a system with windows 2000 Pro. How can i do this you are telling me? Thanks again